# Virtual Machine on ESX hangs up when Hyper-V is activated

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, esxi, windows-server-2022

I have set up an Windows Server 2022 Virtual Maschine on an ESX Server.
[image]

When running this VM it hangs up, after a period of time. You can access the machine by Remote Desktop, but it's reaction is very slow. If you open the task manager, it takes 2-3 minutes until he is showing the CPU-Usage.

With deactivating the Hyper-V-Service the VM is running for 3 days now without hanging.

Any ideas on this?

EDIT: The CPU-Settings in vSphere...
[image]

UPDATE 2022-12-10:

Installed VM-Ware-Tools with CD/ISO-Image.
Hardware-Version is 19.

[image]

But in the "updates" tab in VCenter the hardware-version and vmware-tools version can't be shown. If I click "update status", I get the following error:

> The operation is not supported on the object

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1034495

Comment: "When running this VM it hangs up, after a period of time. You can access the machine by Remote Desktop, but it's reaction is very slow." - I had a similar problem on Windows Server 2019, turned out, it was caused by a memory leak.

Comment: @Ramhound memory consumption seem to be OK. Nothing unusual in task manager.

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue with just running the service, so the hanging issue is likely something else. VMware does support enabling Hyper-V on VMs for virtualization-based security (though they don't technically support *nested* VMs, if that's what you're doing). Make sure vmtools is updated on the VM, and check that the vm compatibility level is at least hardware version 18.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem by re-enabling the hyper-v service? If you can reliably say it's only that service, then it may be worth reporting to vmware

Comment: @Cpt.Whale thanks. I will check this Monday.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I updated the post. Now having the current vmware tools, I reenabled the hyper-v-service.